# Integrate taobao sdk in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, shopping-cart

I have a requirement to develop a site like a Taobao agent in ASP.Net. I don't understand Chinese so I cannot able find docs/article on this in english.However I have come to know to know that there is a c# sdk for Taobao. But I cannot able to find documentation in English. So is there are any documentation of taobao in English or I should translate it via google.

Also as I don't know much about how taobao agent works, can some one provide me a link/article/blog in english about this, so that I can fully understand system works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to develope a site like Taobao? Or become a taobao agent? Or know about taobao sdk api? But I am sure taobao doesn't provide Engish documentation。

Comment: Thanks for reply Tianyun. I need to develop a website which is a taobao agent like http://www.65daigou.com/. So I need to implement c# SDK for which I need doc in english. As you said taobao not provide English doc then is there any other way to implement c# SDK?

Answer (score 1):

The task is not a problem if you use Opentao API Key. It provides easy API access to all the greatest marketplaces like Taobao, Tmall, Yahoo.Japan etc.

You just integrate the Key to your site and:

- Have all the Taobao and Tmall goods showcase with prices, vendors and descriptions directly on your site.
- Have goods search on your site, which is more exact and correct than Taobao original search.
- Your e-shop is protected from changes in marketplace’s api and its work is more stable and correct.

You may even run a new e-shop with Taobao, Tmall and other needed marketplace content just in few days as Opentao API Key has its CMS which can be installed on your domain.

Visit http://key.opentao.net for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Need to implement TaoBao API in a project. 
Do you have a links were to register and apply for getting an API key?

Everything is on chines so is so hard to understans..

Answer (score 0):

Try this link: https://open.alibaba.com/us/portal/resourceDetail?articleId=102687&categoryId=101732

And once you create the app go to the link http://my.open.taobao.com/app/router.htm?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID} and select SDK Download from the left menu. They generate all the code for accessing the API, it's easy to use. Unfortunately i still didn't get it working :(
I get an invalid signature error, so i'm trying to figure that out.